# C: Deep function call cause peculiar behaviour?

Tags: c

I have a program that utilize a third-party library (no source code provided).
Let's say we have a function called `DP_AcquireFingerprint()`. This function call will interface with the third-party library to read a fingerprint image from a fingerprint scanner hardware.

When I call this function directly from `main()`, it works fine:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Matrix* mat;
  DP_AcquireFingerprint(&mat); /* Works fine */
}
```

However, this function starts acting weird when buried in a deep function call. Example:

```
void func1(Matrix** mat) {
  DP_AcquireFingerprint(mat);
}

void func2(Matrix** mat) {
  func1(mat);
}

void func3(Matrix** mat) {
  func2(mat);
}

void func4(Matrix** mat) {
  func3(mat);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Matrix* mat;
  func4(&mat); /* Not working! */
}
```

Particularly, the library complained that there is a buffer not enough error, whereas I am pretty sure that I have allocated enough memory in the heap to store the fingerprint image (inside this function).

The question is, what is the difference between the first and the second code snippet? Is there any possibilities for a function to behave differently if called in different location?

Comment: Should the original `mat` pointer be initialized before you pass it to this function, or is that the purpose of the function?

Comment: The initialization is done within the function.

Answer (score 2):

If your buffer allocation is incorrect then it's perfectly possible that the reorganisation of code would change behaviour. Buffer overrun is undefined behaviour and so could well differ with such a reorganisation. I think you need to look again at the buffer allocation code which is not present in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug your program after enabling debugger information when compiling your source code (on Linux, that means compile and link with `gcc -g -Wall`, then using `gdb`)?